# Copy as values with formatting instead of pasting values with the formula

Tags: excel, vba

The ACTUAL code copies the data and pastes with formula into the separate workbooks.
I need to copy the data and paste as values whilst preserving all the formatting and border lines etc into the separate workbooks. It would be a great help if someone could just use my current code to tweak the code to paste as values with the formatting as I like how my current code works. Only issue is the pasting part comes with the formula.

Something i tried to tweek with my current code is to add this  portion, but still does not work as expected. Thank you very much in advance

```
  **For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
     xWs.Copy
       With xWs.UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
      End With

      If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
           FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
       Else**
```

---

### ACTUAL CODE BELOW

```
  Sub SplitWorkbook()

   Dim FileExtStr As String 
   Dim FileFormatNum As Long 
   Dim xWs As Worksheet 
   Dim xWb As Workbook 
   Dim FolderName As String

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
   DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
   FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
   MkDir FolderName

       For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
       xWs.Copy
         If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
          FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
            Else
           Select Case xWb.FileFormat
        Case 51:
          FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
          If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
          FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
        Else
          FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        End If
        Case 56:
          FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Case Else:
          FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
        End If

        xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr
         Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
         Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        Next
        MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub
```

Comment: `xWs.Copy` creates a new workbook with that sheet. How are the formats not preserved? Note, it seems like you should be calling `.Value = .Value` on the new sheet, not `xWs`.

Comment: Sorry I ran my code and realised the code copy pastes existing formula into values on the same sheet in the existing workbook. I want to know how to copy paste into values using my current code into the split workbooks?

Comment: The new worksheet becomes the active one. You can do `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value`.